# SSIS : delete rows after an update or insert

Tags: sql-server, etl, ssis

Here is the following situation:
I have a table of **StudentsA** which needs to be synchronized with another table, on a different server, **StudentsB**. It's a one-way sync from A to B.
Since the table StudentsA can hold a large number of rows, we have a table called **StudentsSync** (on the input server) containing the ID of **StudentsA** which have been modified since the last copy from **StudentsA** to **StudentsB**.

I made the following SSIS Data Flow task:

[image]

The only problem is that I need to DELETE the row from **StudentsSync** after a successful copy or update. Something like this:

[image]

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved using 3 methods

1.If your `target` table in  `OutputDB` has `TimeStamp` columns such as  `Create` and `modified TimeStamp` then rows which have got `updated` or `inserted` can be obtained by writing a simple query. You need to write the below query in the `execte sql task` in `Control Flow` to `delete` those rows in `Sync` Table .

```
Delete from SyncTable
where keyColumn in (Select primary_key from target 
where ModifiedTimeStamp >= GETDATE() or (ModifiedTimeStamp is null
and CreateTimeStamp>=GETDATE()))
```

I assume `StudentsA's` `primary key` is present in `Sync` table along with `primary key` of `Target` table. The above condition basically checks, if a `new row` is `added` then `CreateTimeStamp` column will have `current` date and `modifiedTimeStamp` will be `null` else if the values are `updated` then the `modifiedTimeStamp` will have current date

The above query will work if you have `TimeStamp` columns in your `target` table which i feel  should be there if your loading data into `Data Warehouse`

2.You can use `MERGE` syntax to perform the update and insert in `Control Flow` with `Execute SQL Task`.No need to use `Data Flow Task` .The below query can be used even if you don't have any `TimeStamp columns`

```
DECLARE @Output TABLE ( ActionType VARCHAR(20), SourcePrimaryKey INT)

MERGE StudentsB  AS TARGET
USING StudentsA  AS SOURCE 
ON (TARGET.CommonColumn = SOURCE.CommonColumn) 

WHEN MATCHED 
THEN 
UPDATE SET TARGET.column = SOURCE.Column,TARGET.ModifiedTimeStamp=GETDATE()

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT (col1,col2,Col3) 
VALUES (SOURCE.col1, SOURCE.col2, SOURCE.Col3)

OUTPUT $action, 
INSERTED.PrimaryKey AS SourcePrimaryKey INTO @Output

Delete from SyncTable
where PrimaryKey in (Select SourcePrimaryKey from @Output
                     where ActionType ='INSERT' or ActionType='UPDATE')
```

The code is not tested as i'm running out of time .but at-least it should give you a fair idea how to proceed . .For furthur detail on `MERGE` syntax read [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507444/t-sql-merge-finding-out-which-action-it-took)

3.Use `Multicast` Component to `duplicate` the dataset for `Insert` and `Update` .Connect a `MULTICAST` to `lookmatch` output and another multicast to `Lookup No match output`

[image]

Comment: 3rd solution seems the best fit to my problem. I don't think the first 2 would work using DBs on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a task after "Update existing entry" and after "Insert new entry" to add the student ID to a variable which will contain the list of IDs to delete.
2. Enclose all of the tasks in a sequence container.
3. After the sequence container executes add a task to delete all the records from the sync table that are in that variable you've been populating.

Comment: You `cannot` add a component after `Destination`(Insert new entry) AFAIK till SSIS 2008. It will just give you an `error Output`