# SSIS prevent delete after insert if insert fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a requirement to use SSIS to pull data from somewhere, put it in a SQL database table, then delete the source data. I have seen this answer [SSIS : delete rows after an update or insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701859/ssis-delete-rows-after-an-update-or-insert) and option #3 (add a multicast to split the 2 operations) looks good but I have a concern...

What happens if the insert to the destination fails? Will my records still be deleted? I want to make sure I don't lose any data by accident due to a failed insert - is there a better way?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 to execute the SSIS package.

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, your source is excel/csv/flat file or another database table ? Anyway if you're using `Data flow task` and insertion fails, the package won't execute further unless you tweak in properties. So by default, your source won't delete if insertion fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a multicast, then yes, the delete will happen even if the insert fails.   If you want to make the delete dependent on the insert, you would need to do them in separate consecutive tasks with a precedence constraint between them.

Comment: Thanks. If I've understood you right, I'm making 2 entries in the control flow that are linked with a green arrow with constraint on success. Then in my first data flow I do the inserts and the 2nd one I do the deletes?